# c++0x: resolving ambiguity between function-definition followed by empty-declaration and simple-declaration

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, specifications

I am having an issue with wrapping my head around an apparent ambiguity in the c++0x spec, see also: http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/

Assume we have the code

```
void foo() {};
```

Personally I interpret the code as a `function-definition` followed by an `empty-declaration`. But, looking at the grammar spec, I'd say that this could just as easily be interpreted as a `simple-declaration`, which is part of `block-declaration` and hence mentioned sooner in the list of `declaration`...

Here's my explanation for how this can be parsed as a simple-declaration:

```
void foo() {};"
```

-> simple-declaration

```
void
```

-> decl-specifier-seq -> decl-specifier -> type-specifier -> trailing-type-
specifier -> simple-type-specifier

```
foo() {}
```

-> init declarator-list -> init-declarator

```
foo()
```

-> declarator -> ptr-declarator -> noptr-declarator

```
foo
```

-> declarator-id -> ...

```
()
```

-> parameters-and-qualifiers

```
{}
```

-> initializer -> braced-init-list

So this should be possible to be parsed as a simple-declaration.

I was told that 6.8 of the spec should be used to disambiguate this case, but I don't quite understand why. Is a `simple-declaration` an `expression-statement` since it ends with an `;`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are right. It's an ambiguity and I'm not aware of a paragraph that resolves it in the spec.

There are other ambiguities in the C++0x spec that are not explicitly resolved, but that (hopefully) are going to be implemented in the straight forward way by compilers. For example, the following can be parsed as both the definition of a nested class `B` and as the definition of an unnamed bitfield having size `0` of the underlying type `struct B`. The latter interpretation would render the program invalid).

```
struct C { constexpr operator int() { return 0; } }; 
struct A { struct B : C { }; };
```

Another example

```
struct A {
  // is 0 a 'brace-or-equal-initializer' or a 'pure-specifier'?
  virtual void f() = 0;
};
```

Clang recently had to fix the following because it got it the wrong way (it parsed it as initializing a variable `f`, instead of making a function pure).

```
typedef void T();
struct B : A {
  // B::f overrides A::f
  T f = 0;
};
```

Comment: wait... `constexpr operator int()` means that the *class identifier* `C` is convertible to int at compile time ? Isn't it rather that `constexpr `objects of type `C` will be converted to `int` ? (like in `struct A { static const C c; struct B : c {}; };`, which is ill formed as a zero-length bitfield member, but I hope you see the point)

Comment: @Alex `C{}` is a value constructed `C` object.

Comment: In order for your first example to work, `C{}` would also have to be `constexpr` (as the class instance would need to be created at compile-time), so the constructor would need to be declared `constexpr`.

Comment: @Nicol the constructor of `C` is not called. It's value-initialization, and the default constructor of `C` is trivial. So by rules of clause 8.5, we are not calling any constructor. But disregarding that, the implicitly declared constructor of `C` *is* `constexpr` by the rules of 12.1p6 and 7.1.5. But in any case, these are semantic considerations. The code semantically is ill-formed in any case. Whether `C{}` is a valid const expression is irrelevant. It can be parsed as one.